# Kerberos impersonation of a Spark Context at runtime

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, kerberos, impersonation

I have a Spark application executing various jobs for different users simultaneously, via several Spark sessions on several threads.

My customer would like to kerberize his hadoop cluster. I wonder if there is a way to configure impersonation such as each of these jobs would be ran with the different proxy users.
From what I see in spark conf and code, it's not possible to do that at runtime for a specific context, but I'm not familiar with Kerberos nor with this part of Spark.

Anyone can confirm/infirm this ?